# "Xively GPRS-master library" GET example with the sim900 icomsat shield for arduino

Tags: arduino, gprs, xively

I'm trying to use this example from the Xively_GPRS-master library (https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Xively_GPRS) to get data of the xively website, and I get only this in the serial monitor for arduino:

"Reading from Xively example

IP =191.171.127.94"

I'm using the icomsat 1.1 sim900 based shield for arduino from Itead Studio.

Someone can help me? ThankYou!

```
#include <GPRSClient.h>
#include <Xively.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PIN_TX 2
#define PIN_RX 3

// Your Xively key to let you upload data
char xivelyKey[] = "yGr24HFXpc2IVMACSdmyypR9d6ubk8XX2f3RRFJ2phhR96AR";

// Define the string for our datastream ID
char sensorId[] = "sensor";

XivelyDatastream datastreams[] = {
  XivelyDatastream(sensorId, strlen(sensorId), DATASTREAM_FLOAT),
};
// Finally, wrap the datastreams into a feed
XivelyFeed feed(675207838, datastreams, 1 /* number of datastreams */);

char apn[] = "tim.br";
char user[] = "tim";
char pass[] = "tim";
GPRSClient gprs(PIN_TX,PIN_RX,4800,apn,user,pass);
XivelyClient xivelyclient(gprs);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(4800);

  Serial.println("Reading from Xively example");
  Serial.println();

  gprs.init();
  while(false == gprs.join()) {
    Serial.println("connect error");
    delay(2000);
  }

  // successful DHCP
  Serial.print("IP =");
  Serial.println(gprs.getIPAddress());
}

void loop() {
  int ret = xivelyclient.get(feed, xivelyKey);

  if (ret > 0){
    Serial.println("Datastream is...");
    Serial.println(feed[0]);
    Serial.print("Temperature is: ");
    Serial.println(feed[0].getFloat());
  }


  Serial.println();
  delay(15000UL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough to tell what the problem is here. Can you post your serial monitor output? Also, are you seeing any requests in the Xively Workbench Request Log? That would be the first place to check.